# Add a WHERE to a joined table

Tags: magento-1.8, collection, eav

I am trying to create an Inner join between two tables but am running into a problem with the second table. There is a one to many relationship with the mageuserid in Main table and the entity_id in CCP. I need to only return the store state value in ccp where ccp.attribute_id = x. How would I accomplish that?

```
$collectionfetch=Mage::getModel('marketplace/userprofile')->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('wantpartner',array('eq'=>1))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('partnerstatus',array('eq'=>'Seller'))
                        ->addFieldToFilter('logopic',array('neq'=>''));
        $prefix = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix();
        $collectionfetch->getSelect()
        ->join(array("ccp" => $prefix."customer_entity_varchar"),"ccp.entity_id = main_table.mageuserid",array("store_state" => "value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need get attribute details using  `Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer') Model by attribute code .`

If your attribute code is `store_state` the you can get it attribute table name and attribute using below code.

```
$store_state  = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer')->getAttribute('store_state');

$tablename=$store_state->getBackend()->getTable();
```

**$table  been taken by static.it can take dynamic by above code**

```
$attributeId=$store_state->getAttributeId()
```

As `customer_entity_varchar` table has `lots of record` with `different attribute` so you need to `put attribute id in join query condition`

```
$collectionfetch->getSelect()->joinLeft(
    array('ccp' =>$store_state->getBackend()->getTable()),
    'ccp.entity_id = main_table.mageuserid
    AND ccp.attribute_id = '.(int) $store_state->getAttributeId() . '
    ',
    array('store_state'=>'value'));
```

Comment: Makes sense to me! I tried it out and received a Fatal Error for using the joinLeft function

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Webkul_Marketplace_Model_Mysql4_Userprofile_Collection::joinLeft() in  /public_html/app/code/local/Webkul/Sellers/Block/Sellers.php on line 15

Comment: Added ->getSelect() before joinLeft() and it works! Thanks! 

$collectionfetch->getSelect()->joinLeft(
      array('ccp' =>$store_state->getBackend()->getTable()),
      'ccp.entity_id = main_table.mageuserid
      AND ccp.attribute_id = '.(int) $store_state->getAttributeId() . '
      ',
      array('store_state'=>'value'));